# Keep getting error when argument is [1, 2, 2]

Tags: python

```py
def is_ascending(items):
  if len(items) == 0 or 1:
    return True
  for i in range(len(items) - 1):
    if items[i] >= items[i + 1]:
      return False
  return True
```

Comment: Problem is with 0 or 1. You need to check the condition. 

```
  if len(items) == 0 or len(items) == 1:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
if len(items) == 0 or 1:
```

This snippet doesn't do what you think it does. It's essentially evaluated like

```py
if (len(items) == 0) or (1):
```

which is always True since the part after the "or" is True (so the whole function returns True. What you want is

```py
if (len(items) == 0) or (len(items) == 1):
```

or simpler

```py
if len(items) <= 1:
```